# Android Duplicate File Exception

Tags: android

I have downloaded the Jackson2 libraries to include in an android class.  I get this error upon building:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.  com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE   File1: \app\libs\jackson-core-2.9.1.jar     File2: \app\libs\jackson-databind-2.9.1.jar     File3: \app\libs\jackson-annotations-2.9.1.jar

I searched the internet and found this to be the most common answer:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude  "META-INF/license.txt"
}
```

However, this doesn't fix the issue above.

Comment: tell me what you'v `exclude` in pakaging option

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude the **exact file name**. From the error log, you can see that the duplicated file is `META-INF/LICENSE` (be aware of the case-sensitive) :

> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE

So, exclude it:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}
```